# findViewById no Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Fui gerar uma ação ao clicar em um `Button`

```
fun cliqueBotao(view : View){
    var texto = findViewById<>(R.id.textoExibicao) as TextView
    texto.setText("Texto alterado")
}
```

Só que o Android Studio ficou reclamando que `findViewById<>` está sem parâmetro. Fiz uma pesquisa rápida e percebi que alguns métodos colocam o valor passado por parâmetro quando o método é criado `fun cliqueBotao(view : View)` dentro do `findViewById<>`

E meu método ficou assim

```
fun cliqueBotao(view : View){
    var texto = findViewById<View>(R.id.textoExibicao) as TextView
    texto.setText("Texto alterado")
}
```

Até agora meu App tá funcionando normal, por que antes não precisava e agora precisa e essa forma está correta?

Agradeço desde já

Answer (score 10):

> Esqueça o FindViewById :)

Usando as "Extensions" tu não precisas mais usar o findViewbyId no Kotlin. Podes acessar as tuas views usando diretamente o ID.
É simples:

1 - No gradle, adicione o plugin:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

2 - Na tua Activity faça o import (Suponhamos que estamos na Main Activity):

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
```

E já está. Podes fazer assim:

```
textoExibicao.setText("Texto alterado")
```

:)

Answer (score 2):

Isso está acontecendo porque você está forçando o tipo do `findViewById` quando faz `as TextView`. Desde a API 26, isso não é mais necessário-- o tipo é inferido automaticamente pra você.

Portanto, pode fazer só assim:

```
var texto = findViewById(R.id.textoExibicao)
texto.setText("Texto alterado")
```

ou melhor ainda:

```
val texto = findViewById(R.id.textoExibicao)
texto.text = "Texto alterado"
```

Answer (score 1):

O plugin `kotlin-android-extensions` foi descontinuado.
Faça a substituição para o view binding

1. Remova o plugin `kotlin-extensions` no `build.gradle` (app) e sincronize (sync)
2. Remova possíveis imports do `kotlinx.android.synthetic` no projeto
3. No `build.gradle`, dentro das chaves do `buildFeatures` adicione a seguinte linha:

`viewBinding = true`

4. No método onCreate(), faça a declaração do viewBinding chamando o método inflate, exemplo:

```
private lateinit var binding: ResultProfileBinding
 
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
   binding = ResultProfileBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
   val view = binding.root
   setContentView(view) 
}
```

Agora você poderá utilizar o viewBinding para chamar as views

```
binding.name.text = viewModel.name
binding.button.setOnClickListener { viewModel.userClicked() }
```

doc: [Kotlin Extensions Deprecated](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration)

Answer (score 0):

API 28,
A apply plugin: '**kotlin-android-extensions**' já vem inserida no Glade por padrão.

Só precisei do `import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*`

```
fun actionButton(view: View){
    val text = "O texto escolhido: "
    textSelection.text = text
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1- Adicionar o viewBinding no gradle modules:

```
viewBinding{
    enabled = true
}
```

2- Na activity crie uma variável lateinit binding

```
lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
```

3- No metodo onCreate() instancia a variavel binding

```
binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
```

4- Passe o binding.root como parametro no metodo setContentView()

```
setContentView(binding.root)
```

A partir daí você pode acessar as views do xml utilizando a variável binding + id da view

fonte:
https://www.dio.me/articles/resumo-sobre-a-utilizacao-do-viewbinding

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).